# Link tags in iframe widget

Tags: seo, iframe, widgets, headers

I have a rating community-site and I´m offering little `iframe` widgets with the average rating and some little other info.

Does it make sense (for visibility, SEO) to add link tags to the `head` like:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="rssfeed" />
<link rel="index" title="main-profile" href="main-profile">
```

To get a logical association of the widget to relating pages? How would you do this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it will make any sense to add `link` tag like this as search engine will identify it without explicitly mentioning it through `link` tag.

But if you want to block crawlers, you may have to put `rel=noindex` tag!